# Command after apt-get install is not executing in script

Tags: ssh, scripting, session

I'm writing a script which is meant to initially set up my Droplet. In the script, I'm opening ssh connection with my Ubuntu 14.04 server as follows (with `USER` and `REMOTE` variables previously defined):

```
ssh -t -t $USER@$REMOTE <<'ENDSSH'
ENDSSH
```

Inside of that SSH connection, I have multiple commands which I want to execute - installing Node.js, updating npm, installing MongoDB and so on.

But, once I do a `apt-get install` command, other commands do not get executed.

So, if I have this:

```
ssh -t -t $USER@$REMOTE <<'ENDSSH'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo apt-get install -y npm
ENDSSH
```

Command `sudo apt-get install -y npm` won't be executed. Now, I know that I can install multiple packages within the same `apt-get install` command, but this is not what I'm asking, since other commands afterwards won't get executed than. This example I just wrote out of simplicity so I can explain my problem.

I came across questions like [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/489939/ssh-session-never-closes-when-executing-apt-get-install) where they say I should put multiple `-t` flags when opening `ssh` connection, which I'm doing, but that doesn't help.

What am I doing wrong?